# Why is my DelegatingHandler firing for MVC requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a hybrid MVC/Web API project and I added a simple DelegatingHandler implementation to wrap the API responses. This works great, but the handler is also being invoked for requests to MVC controllers. My understanding is that DelegatingHandlers are only invoked for API routes.

I'm using OWIN and some attribute routes if that matters. The relevant code in Startup.cs is:

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
// ...
var debugging = HttpContext.Current == null || HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled;
config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ApiResponseDelegatingHandler(debugging));
```

This causes both API and web requests to be wrapped and sent as JSON. Commenting it out resolves the problem but API requests are not wrapped. The error message on a web page is:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'xxx'. No
>   route data was found for this request.

I tried forcing the order that routes are registered so that MVC routes are added before Web API but that didn't help.

Comment: I can implement this successfully using an ActionFilterAttribute but that doesn't handle errors.

Comment: You can have handler in MVC as well, I think the behaviour is the expected one. What you can do is verify if the route found for the given request is in the namespace where you have your API controllers. But IMO you should split the two projects.

Comment: Action filters do handle errors, but up in the stack - errors that occur in the controller itself.

Comment: It's a small project and I don't want to split it, I've regretted doing that in the past because it doubles the deployments with no benefit. Anyway, I can reproduce it and it's due to OWIN, I'm now waiting to find out if it's a bug. It's definitely not the expected behavior, message handlers should only be activated for API routes.

Comment: You're right, I was pretty sure MVC had message handlers as well, always learning http://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf

Comment: @JamieIde did you submit a bug for this? If so could you share the link, might be quite useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easy to reproduce and I'm not sure if it's a bug or not.

- Create a new web app using the ASP.NET MVC template
- Install the Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin and
  Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb NuGet packages
- Move Web API startup from WebApiConfig.cs to a new Startup.cs file
- Create a DelegatingHandler and add it to config.MessageHandlers in the Startup class
- The DelegatingHandler will be invoked for MVC and API requests

I tried several combinations of initializing in Startup.cs and WebApiConfig.cs without success. If you;re not using attribute routing, the solution is to add the handler to the route. If you are, the only workaround I found was to examine the route in the handler and only wrap the API response if the route starts with "/api/".

```
public class WtfDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (request.RequestUri.LocalPath.StartsWith("/api/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            response = new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Content = new StringContent("I'm an API response")
            };
        }

        return response;
    }

}
```